# How could i fix this issue

Tags: testng, testautomationfx

```
class Test_Registeration
@Test(groups = "group1")


class Test_Registeration
@Test(groups = "group2", dependsOnGroups = "group1")
```

When I use these annotations it gives me this error that it doesn’t exist

```
Error:
DependencyMap::Method "Test_LoginPage.Test()[pri:0, instance:Test_LoginPage@7a419da4]" depends on nonexistent group "group1"
```

I checked spelling and rebuilt the project but it still gives the same output.

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups), you are missing some brackets.

The correct usage would be:

`@Test(groups = { "group1" })`

`@Test(groups = { "group2" }, dependsOnGroups =  { "group1" })`